# Menu item call twice in fragment android

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, fragment, double-click

```
In fragment when i click on menu item , it calls function twice one is from previous fragment and other one is from existing fragment.

Fragment 1:
     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId() == R.id.refresh){
                RetryCallMap();
                return true;
            }else
            return false;
        }
Fragment 2:
     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId() == R.id.refresh){
                RetryCall();
                return true;
            }else
            return false;
        }
MainActivity :

    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.map) {
                pushFragments("mapFragment", new MapFragment(), true, true);
                return true;
            }
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                this.drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawableListView);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

These are the fragments and my MainActivity i am refreshing fragment by on menu item click so that if internet connection not found or any other problem occurs while fetching for i can refresh the page.

Comment: so check is fragment visible in `onOptionsItemSelected()`

Comment: please paste code of menu from previous fragment for better reference.

Comment: We also had same issue. Please try android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" in all the parent layouts for fragment and their parent activity.

Answer (score 1):

Returning `true` in onOptionsItemSelected() function worked for me.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.refresh){
            RetryCall();
            return true;
        }else
        return true;
    }
```